# Adding icons to http response

Tags: java, html, http, server, icons

I'm using **com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer**  class as a simple server that sends the browser html string as response.
The html is created on the server side and then I'm sending it to the browser to be presented.
This html contains some icons and I can't find how to attach these icons to the response.

for example, part of my html is:

```
+ "<i class=\"fa float-right-label\"> "
                        + "<a href =\"javascript:newWindow()\"><img src=\"log.png\" alt=\"Log History\" height=\"30\" width=\"30\" border=0></a>"
                        + "</i></label> " + "<ul class=\"animate\">";
```

that uses **log.png** icon. 
Although I have the icon in my resource folder in my project, it is not getting send.

I'm guessing that there should be some "set resource" method, but didn't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't really include the icons in the response.  When the browser parses the HTML it will issue an HTTP get for the image.  Your server will serve it to the browser in the same manner that it serves other static content.

Comment: You mean that in my handle(HttpExchange arg0) method I need to check the path of org0 and if it a icon name then I will send the appropriate icon?

Comment: Your server should be able to serve static content without you having to do anything.  I don't know much about com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer but I do know if you use Jetty or Tomcat or similar (application server) you can configure it to serve static content from the file system.  I don't know what your requirements are or why you picked HttpServer but after a quick look at the docs it looks like you might have to handle those static resource requests yourself.  Very painful IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
I choose this server and not sonething loke Tomcat, because in my case I just need a simple server, I don't need something as heavy as Tomcat. But I added another handler for the resources and it works fine.